# AltGr selectively dropped in communication chain on Finnish keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using Kubuntu 14 LTS on two machines, one as 32-bit version and the other as 64-bit version. I have been using x2x to control the former system from the keyboard and mouse of the latter. I have also been using rdesktop on the display of the 32-bit system to get access to external Windows 7 systems. Everything has worked fine, including typing symbols needing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> on the Finnish keyboard (such as €@£${[]}\|~). I have used this setup daily for several years.

Now I got a new windows 7 system and I try use xfreerdp instead of rdesktop (because I need Network Level Authentication) for the same kind of display, keyboard and mouse access sharing. However, I don't get any of the symbols behind <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> through from the 64-bit system via the 32-bit system to Windows 7. According to xev AltGr will not get through at all. The keyboard mappings are OK (by `setxkbmap -layout fi`; symbols like öÖäÄåÅ get through). What's more peculiar, the following things seem to work OK with all the symbols mentioned:

1. €@£${[]}\|~ get through OK, if I use the Windows 7 system directly from either the 64-system or the 32-bit system using the keyboard attached directly to the system.
2. €@£${[]}\|~ also get through correctly via x2x up to the machine running xfreerdp, but not from there via xfreerdp to the Windows 7 machine.
3. Things are as bad as that if I try to use xfreerdp instead of rdesktop for accessing an older Windows 7 system with the same Kubuntu systems with an otherwise similar arrangement.

Are there any hints what to do to correct or circumvent the problem (easier to use than always having a window containing the special characters €@£${[]}\|~ open on the Windows machine for copying and pasting them e.g. into a cygwin terminal window for unix shell commands)?